# CorePlot real time graphing

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I'm new to coreplot and not sure quite where to start. I would like to plot data points as they arrive.  I'm recording finger touches and how long between each touch.  I would like to plot them as they are happening.

Thanks for any pointers.

rd42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:` method on your plot to add data points. The plot will call your datasource to load the new data. There is a corresponding delete method as well if you want to drop off the old data points. The alternative is to call `-reloadData` on the plot, but that's unnecessary if the old data points haven't changed.